# How to convert Java Hashmap Hierarchy to its equivalent in Redis Cache?

Tags: java, redis, memcached

I have the following Job class representing runs of a job. I have a list of start and end times in Job class because the same Job can be rerun.

```
public class Job {

      private final List<Timestamp> jobStartTimes = new SortedList<>();
      private final List<Timestamp> jobEndTimes = new SortedList<>();
      private String jobName;
      private String jobKey;
      private String host;
      ....
      ....
}
```

I have this Map for querying jobs given jobkey.

```
public class JobMap {

         /**
         * Here value of 'String' key is jobKey
         */
         private final Map<String, Job> jobCache;
}
```

I have also created the following hierarchy of hashmaps for storing (starttime, jobKey) and (endtime, jobkey) entries in Map so that I can retrieve job records faster. This is needed because my queries are timestamp based, for ex: return all jobs that ran between x and y timestamp.

```
public class YearCache<T> {

        /**
         * Here value of 'Integer' key is month number (0, 11)
         */
        private final Map<Integer, MonthCache> monthCache;
}

public class MonthCache {

        /**
         * Here value of 'Integer' key is week number in a month(0, 4)
         */
        private final Map<Integer, WeekCache> weekCache;
}

public class WeekCache {

        /**
         * Here value of 'Integer' key is day number in a week (0, 6)
         */
        private final Map<Integer, DayCache> dayCache;
}

private class DayCache
{
        /**
         * Here value of 'Integer' key is hour value in a day (0, 23)
         * T is of type String representing jobKey
         */
         private final NavigableMap<Integer, NavigableMap<Timestamp, Set<T>>> hourCache;
}
```

I want to get rid of this Java hashmaps and move to Redis Cache. How can I model this hierarchy in Redis Cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is needed because my queries are timestamp based, for ex: return all jobs that ran between x and y timestamp.

Take a look at *Sorted Set Time Series Pattern* in Redis Time Series Patterns. Details can be found [here](https://redislabs.com/redis-best-practices/time-series/sorted-set-time-series/). You might have to tweak the example by a bit to suit your need. Excerpt from the doc:

```
+---------------+-------------+
| Timestamp     | Temperature |
+---------------+-------------+
| 1511533205001 | 21          |
+---------------+-------------+
| 1511533206001 | 22          |
+---------------+-------------+
```

You can query like this:

```
> ZADD temperature 1511533205001 21
(integer) 1
> ZADD temperature 1511533206001 22
(integer) 1
> ZRANGEBYSCORE temperature -inf +inf WITHSCORES
1) "22"
2) "1511533206001"
3) "21"
4) "1511533207001"
```

This is a simple example. The link discusses an extension to this approach to handle a specific corner case.

For your case, given that you have `jobStartTime` and `jobEndTime`, you might have to use separate sets for `jobStarts` and `jobEnds` keyed by the timestamp in which the job was started/ended. Then:

Let `x` denote the start and `y` denote the end of a job

1. Query all the jobs that were started after `x` from `jobStarts` set
2. Query all the jobs that completed before `y` but started after `x` from `jobsEnds` set
3. Repeated values from the results of step 1 and 2 yields the jobs that were started after `x` and ended before `y`

In your code:

```
public class Job {

      private final List<Timestamp> jobStartTimes = new SortedList<>();
      private final List<Timestamp> jobEndTimes = new SortedList<>();
      ....
      private String jobKey;
      ....
}
```

you're storing all the runs as part of the job. It's better to segregate the job runs separately from the job so that the job details can be cached separately in a set called `jobs`. Then the values of sets `jobStarts` and `jobEnds` can be the jobKey using which you can look up the details from the `jobs` set which stores the job details separately.